# Google Maps Force Closes on GPS Location and Radius Detection (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, location

Good day!

I am currently doing an application wherein if the current GPS location of the user is inside the radius of a certain location, it will return to a toast or activate another activity via intent.

Currently, with Google Markers, I can detect the marker and determine if it's outside or inside the the radius. But, when I tried doing it with the current GPS location, it force closes without any error from Android Studio.

Here is my current code for Google Maps:

```
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,

            }, 10);
        }
        return;
    }

   gMap = googleMap;

        if(!gMap.isMyLocationEnabled())
            gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


        if (myLocation == null) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }

        if(myLocation != null){
            LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 14), 1500, null);
        }


    Marker marker1 = googleMap.addMarker(
            new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(14.6036,120.9834))
                    .title("Recto Station")
    );

    Circle c_recto = gMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(14.6036,120.9834))
    .radius(100)
            .strokeColor(0x7F00FF00)
            .fillColor(0x7F00FF00)
    );
```

Here is the code for the Google Marker which works:

```
        float[] distance_recto = new float[2];

    Location.distanceBetween( marker1.getPosition().latitude, marker1.getPosition().longitude,
            c_recto.getCenter().latitude, c_recto.getCenter().longitude, distance_recto);



    if( distance_recto[0] < c_recto.getRadius()  ){

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Welcome to Recto Station", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PollWebView.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Welcome to Recto Station", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here is the Google Marker code swapped to get the current GPS Location of the user it and force closes on opening of Google Maps:

```
        float[] distance_recto = new float[2];


    Location.distanceBetween( myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(),
            c_recto.getCenter().latitude, c_recto.getCenter().longitude, distance_recto);


    if( distance_recto[0] < c_recto.getRadius()  ){

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Welcome to Recto Station", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PollWebView.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Welcome to Recto Station", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my code to get the answer.

I globalized

```
LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
```